# How to start and stop movie sequence of image node at specific frame in python script?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, keyframes, text-object

I try to playback different video clips one after the other on a mesh face using keyframes.

[image]

I achived pretty interesting result with changing material offset of a solidify modifier by `keyframe` with python. I used this modifier because the model texture is not animatable.

```
screen = bpy.data.objects['TvScreen']
mod = screen.modifiers['Solidify']
mod.keyframe_insert(data_path="material_offset", frame=currentFrame, group='CurrentVideo')
```

[image]

The problem is that all clips inside materials are playing at the same time. Which on the one hand freeze my Blender and on the other hand I have no control over the movie image frame sequence timing.

I tried to set a `keyframe` for `frame_start` in my script but this property is not animatable.

`TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "frame_start" not animatable`.

I also tried to mute the image texture note of all materials and unmute them by keyframe. This fixes the GUI freeze effect but video squences still playing in background.

[image]

So the final question is "How to start and stop movie sequence of image node at specific frame of mp4 by keyframe in final rendering in python script?".

Maybe there is a much better way to achive this "virtual TV model" in blender. Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to answer but I am trying to access the start_frame parameter of a sequence strip in the VSE and my guess is it has to do with this thing called context. Looks like where ever the start_frame is being defined or allocated in it's parameter the context is where it is inherited.
So it seems you have to create a context which is local to your script so any called functions to "play at some start_frame" will be assigning the "start_frame" from a locally created/allocated "context". 
See:
https://blenderartists.org/t/solved-add-effect-strip-transform-for-image-vse-lm18/688456/2
and Ctrl+F: You just need to set the context.

I have read however, this is not so good for when the local allocation is un-allocated you then have a reference which points to ??? or is broken and a potential for blender crash.
See: 
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html
and Ctrl+F: # polygons have been re-allocated

Sounds like there is a start_frame being set from a GLOBAL context in your case so every start_frame=1 and that is a context you have to modify. Good luck I'm just trying to get:
bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(frame_start=frame_start, frame_end=frame_end, type=‘SPEED’)
to use a frame_start from the selected strip and I don't know how to pass a frame_start parameter which equals the frame_start of the already selected strip without having to recreate a new context. I would imagine I could pass by reference but where is the allocated reference?

Anyway the answer is in the inherited context it seems.